# Requirements for accessing and using ImagePicker in React Native w/ Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm currently making an app in React Native with Expo using the latest version. I'm using the Expo Library [ImagePicker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v37.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/) for accessing the Camera and the Camera Roll.

Do I need to include the required Permissions in the App.json / Config for both Android and iOS for the Camera and Camera Roll, OR is the following runtime code checks enough?

Is the below enough for Apple App Store and Google Play approval?

```js
// Asks the user for permission at runtime
ImagePicker.requestCameraRollPermissionsAsync()
ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You don't need to define these permissions in `App.json` file, When you install this module expo will handle the permissions.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks! I'll accept it in 4 min when it allows me to :)